# What statistical test should be used when measuring mean difference between two groups over 3 time points?

Tags: anova, t-test, mean

I have a study that I am having trouble defining. I have two independent groups that I would like to measure various features to see if they are significantly different between each other. The two features revolve around physiological changes (blood flow rate and size of injury). The two groups are labeled as "Moderate" and "Severe".

There are 3 time points (BL, Acute, and Chronic) - where the continuous measures are made for each group (measure blood flow rate and size of injury). Our control is simply the "BL time point" - we do not have control subjects that are also measured in the acute and chronic time point.

Would a two-sample t-test be the way to go? Compare mean difference between moderate and severe for each continuous variable? How do I incorporate time points into this method?

Here is the summary of table below:

```
Injury    |  BL Blood Flow | Acute Blood Flow | Chronic Blood Flow | BL size of injury | Acute size of injury | Chronic size of injury

Severe            0.87             0.5                  0.66                  0                  2                    1
Moderate          0.84             0.68                 0.77                  0                  1.5                 0.9
Moderate          0.9              0.7                  0.84                  0                  1.1                 0.88
Severe            0.89             0.4                  0.59                  0                  2.2                 1.1
```

Comment: Does your data approximately satisfy the assumptions of a t-test?

Comment: Perhaps ANOVA or generalized linear models will be better for your use case, but you need to determine if your data is appropriate for those methods.

Comment: @Galen Do you mind elaborating a little more in terms of if my data is appropriate? I was thinking maybe an RM-ANOVA since time is something we are wanting to look at and see if there is an effect on the measured results over time. My data is not equal (6 subjects for severe and 7 subjects for moderate) but all subjects are measured the same at each time point.

Comment: Univariate and multivariate normality are important. You should compute whether you have adequate statistical power. You should also look for homoschedasticity and sphericity.